# MySQL obtain an average value

Tags: mysql

My head dizzy by this problem.
I have table student like this:

```
[teac_id] [less_id] [cl_id] [stu_id] [semester] [nilai_1] [nilai_2] [nilai_3] [nilai_4]
   3         3         1        1         1       90.00     90.00     90.00     null
   3         3         1        2         1       70.00     100.00    null      null
```

I use composite primary key, and question is how to get result like this:

```
[teac_id] [less_id] [cl_id] [stu_id] [semester] [ AVG ]
   3         3         1       1        1         (nilai_1 + nilai_2 + nilai_3) / 3
   3         3         1       2        1         (nilai_1 + nilai_2) / 2
```

The field don't have value cannot be a divisor.
Thank advance.

Comment: havent try any query? is column nilai_1 - nilai_4 is fixed?

Comment: I make some query, but use divide by default, its not what I want. I want devide is count filed how have value.

Comment: 1. See normalisation. A database table IS NOT a spreadsheet

Comment: use if() function like dmitry answer

Comment: @Strawberry hahaha...you're right, but "normalisation is not panacea".

Comment: Normalisation is perhaps *the* fundamental concept of RDBMSs. If you don't want to normalise, don't bother with the RDBMS!

Comment: @SukmaSaputra it may not be panacea, but nor is "doing it wrong".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If number `nilai_` fields is *fixed* (i.e. you have four `nilai_1..nilai_4`), you can try something like that (note that at least one field should be not null):

```
select teac_id, 
       less_id,
       cl_id, 
       stu_id,
       semester,
       -- average: just sum / count
       (IfNull(nilai_1, 0) + 
        IfNull(nilai_2, 0) +
        IfNull(nilai_3, 0) +
        IfNull(nilai_4, 0)) / 
        (if(nilai_1 is null, 0, 1) + 
         if(nilai_2 is null, 0, 1) +
         if(nilai_3 is null, 0, 1) +
         if(nilai_4 is null, 0, 1)) as AVG
  from MyTable
```

If there's case that all `nilai_1..nilai_4` can *be null in one record*, you have to modify the query:

```
select teac_id, 
       less_id,
       cl_id, 
       stu_id,
       semester,

       case 
         when (nilai_1 is null) and 
              (nilai_2 is null) and
              (nilai_3 is null) and
              (nilai_4 is null) then
           -- special case: all nulls average
           null
         else
           -- average: just sum / count
          (IfNull(nilai_1, 0) + 
           IfNull(nilai_2, 0) +
           IfNull(nilai_3, 0) +
           IfNull(nilai_4, 0)) / 
             (if(nilai_1 is null, 0, 1) + 
              if(nilai_2 is null, 0, 1) +
              if(nilai_3 is null, 0, 1) +
              if(nilai_4 is null, 0, 1)) 
       end as AVG
  from MyTable
```

Comment: This should work perfect unless all are null. Otherwise a DBZ will be raised.

Comment: @Ravinder: Thank you, you're quite right: all nulls case should be treated separatedly

Comment: thank you @Dmitry Bycenko your code solf my problem, it's look very easy to you. :P